# Finding the customers who hasn't bought anything from a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are my tables:

```
Customers:
- CustomerId
- Name
- Address
- ContactNumber


ProductOrders:
-PorderKey
-CustomerId
-ProductId


Product:
-ProductId
-ProductName
-ProductDescription
```

Is it possible to find the customers who hasn't bought anything yet? If so How should I design my query?

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: Let me add more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` does what you want:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where c.customerid not in (select po.customerid from productorders po);
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT columns, I, actually, want FROM first_table X LEFT JOIN lookup_table y ON y.first_table_id = x.id WHERE y.some_not_nullable_column IS NULL